# XOR encrypting of a float-array in c

Tags: c, encryption, floating-point, bit-manipulation, xor

I want to encrypt a float-type array and decode it again with the same function. I have read several threads on the web but i couldn't find a solution that makes me happy. 
I tried to cast the float-type-pointer to char* and XOR the result with my char-typed key. 
Here my encode function:

```
const char* key = "mykey";
int keylen = sizeof(key) / sizeof(key[0]);

void encodeData(float *data, int size)
{
    int bytes = (int)(sizeof(float)/sizeof(char));

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<bytes; j++)
        {
            data[i] = *(((char *)&data[i]) + j) ^ (key[(bytes*i)%keylen]);
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling works but i don't get the same results after en- and decoding. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you use `sizeof` on a pointer, you get the size of the pointer and not what it points to. Either use `strlen` to get the length of the string, or make `key` an array.

Comment: The left hand side of the assignment is wrong. Instead of `data[i] = `  it should be `*(((char *)&data[i]) + j) =`

Comment: Also, `sizeof(char)` is defined by the C standard specification to always be `1`.

Comment: Also, `key[(bytes*i)%keylen]` is probably not what you want.

Comment: Lastly, you only need *one* cast, if you use a temporary pointer to `char`, like `char *tmp = (char *) data;`. Then you can use `tmp` instead of the pointer arithmetic and casting in the loop. As well as only have a single loop.

Comment: And the next question would be - how do you intend to use the resulting data without violatin the *strict aliasing*?

Comment: "but i don't get the same results after en- and decoding." --> What inputs were used?  What was the result?  How did code handle the function results and showed the value of `data`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg strlen is not a good idea in this case - the float array might contain intermediate null values, but the end does not necessarily have to be null terminated.

Comment: @Aconcagua I mean to use `strlen` to get the length of the `key`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg And why should the latter one *not* contain intermediate null values?

Comment: @Aconcagua Because `const char* key = "mykey";`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg :) have been inattentive... Sorry. I am used to keys being arrays with arbitrary data...

Comment: @Aconcagua Don't worry to much about it, it happens to everyone. Sometimes it's hard to see all the code for the trees, or something to that effect. :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
void encodeData(float *data, int size) 
{ 
     int bytes = (int)(sizeof(float)/sizeof(char)); 
     char *tmp = (char *) data; 
     for(int i=0; i<bytes*size; i++) 
     { 
         *(tmp+i) = *(tmp+i) ^ key[i%keylen]; 
     } 
     data = (float*) tmp; 
 }
```

Comment: Don't post the response as an answer. You can update the question body, marking it as an update.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Normally, he shouldn't - but this time, the response contains the solution, too, so should be fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, then perhaps it should be separated into the solution part and the response part

Comment: This is a poor answer. An answer should explain why each change was made.

Comment: Tip: The casting to/from `float*` should be done in the caller. That will allow your function to work on anything.

Comment: `data = (float*) tmp;` serves no purpose.  Suggest dropping it.  `/sizeof(char)` also of little value.

Comment: 1) More portable to use `unsigned char` than `char`.  2) `size_t` is the best type for object sizes and array indexing.  Not much issue with `float` though.

Comment: Unclear why code using pointer addition with `*(tmp+i)` and in the same line use `[]` with `key[i%keylen]`.  Consider `tmp[i] ^= key[i%keylen];`